# How would I go about forming this controller correctly in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I define in my controller to run and do the following when the Class is fetched in URL;

I need to find all "jobs" to current_user I'm guessing something like this;

```
@joblisting = current_user.Joblisting.find(params[:id])
```

Then I need to take those jobs and check if their column "job_status" has the text "completed" in them or other"

If the jobs_status is "completed" then I need to run code so I do an "if"

I would have to pass the calculation.

```
@joblisting = current_user.Joblisting.find(params[:id])
if @joblisting.where(:project_status => "completed")
  number_to_currency(current_user.Joblisting.where(:project_status => 'completed').sum('jobprice') * 1.60 - current_user.Joblisting.where(:project_status => 'completed').sum('jobprice')) 
  Notifier.notify_payout(current_user).deliver
  @joblisting.project_status = 'paid'
  @joblisting.save
end
```

This is what I've got and I'm stuck with passing the calculation to the Notifier.notify_payout template.

I'm sure whomever knows rails better then me, will right away see my mistakes.

Comment: Have you declared the relation between a User and a JodListing? By relation I mean has_one, has_many, or belongs_to? I guess your User has_many JobListing, am I right?

Comment: Yes relations are declared. You are correct.

Comment: Kansha, got to learn somewhere and I'm sure its a mess but I'll learn with time to clean it up or keep it clean in first place. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user1924165 Can you try `current_user.joblistings.find(params[:id])` and tell me if it raises an error ? (instead of `current_user.Joblistings`)

Comment: Yeah current_user.joblisting.find(params[:id]) does raise an error. I have been using Job listing... model is Joblistings

Comment: @MrYoshiji  
Yeah current_user.joblisting.find(params[:id]) does raise an error. I have been using Job listing... model is Joblistings

Comment: @user1924165 If your model name is `Joblistings` you must use `current_user.Joblistings.find(params[:id])`... Acording to your code you are calling on the `Joblisting` class, which doesn't exist. Also, by convention you should use singular names for your models.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you producing an error, or do you want the code to be written to be efficient and beautiful?

Comment: @jason328 I'm producing an error. :) I'll clean it up later.

Comment: Right now, I've re-written it to; ` @joblisting = Joblisting.where(:developer_id => current_developer[:id]) if @joblisting.where(:project_status => "completed") Notifier.notify_payout(current_developer).deliver end ` and that does pull everything up for me, as well sends the notifier email, however after sending the email I'd like to update the :project_status column text from "completed" to "paid". I'm not sure how to do so only the posts for that current_developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer will not give you the code you seek. I'm doing this because I feel like you still have a lot to learn, but I will tell you what to do, just not give you the code. If you say that this line of code works....

```
 @joblisting = Joblisting.where(:developer_id => current_developer[:id])
 if @joblisting.where(:project_status => "completed")
   Notifier.notify_payout(current_developer).deliver
 end
```

then so be it. As for updating the `:project_status` column from "completed" to "paid", there can be multiply ways to handle this. You could create a method inside your model (let's call it `project_is_paid`) that changes project status to paid and declare it inside `notify_payout` method on success.

But that might be confusing for someone else looking at your code and wondering why all of a sudden the record is changing from "completed" to "paid" inside the database. Plus you would have to pass the joblisting object as an argument which is even more work.

Another way to think of it is to just write a simple conditional statement inside the controller. If the mail is delivered, then call the method `project_is_paid`. Just be careful not to start adding all this logic to your controller, your controller should be concise and short. Let the model deal with the logic.

I want to conclude with going back to your working controller code you posted. I'm willing to bet that you can turn the two following lines into one.

```
 @joblisting = Joblisting.where(:developer_id => current_developer[:id])
 if @joblisting.where(:project_status => "completed")
```

Why do I say that? Well you are making two queries to the same table `Job Listings`. Here is a little help if you can't figure out how... [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

And if I failed to answer your latest question in the comments, I'm sorry. Post an update in your question and I would be happy to update my own answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was real nice of you. I'm learning and you are right, I've got a lot to learn and you do that by getting nice comments from folks like yourself and learning on mistakes. That code works, but its not at all a good approach nor clean. Thank you, I'll post if I figure something out.

Comment: No problem. Let us know how it turns out and if you get stuck, we can help you out.

Comment: I was scratching my head how to make that shorter while reading through the supporting link you've posted to shorten the queries and I came up with these two. Haven't tested them yet, just thought I'd get your opinion; http://pastie.org/private/dke0w8xvqqscamvney8xfq

Comment: In the code you showed me in the link, you have two different types of SQL queries. In the first query you are wanting to run two where clauses. In the second one you want to find all queries that match the current developer and as a complete project. My question is do you expect multiple matches to be returned? If you expect only one match to ever return, I would go with just using the where clause. If multiple, then use find all. And if you want to test something out, just type the code in your rails console. I'll let you figure out if it works via the rails console.

Comment: I would also take a look at the method `exists?` you used in your controller code. Don't be afraid to use google :) http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class

Comment: the second one is what I thought I was more after probably with the find all. Since I'm trying to do two things, locate all postings that belong to the developer and only ones that have been marked as "completed" in the db. Then, send notification and a few other things before updating it to "paid" from "complete". Thanks for the help. I'm learning, it will take some time, however very refreshing from markup development. Fun stuff. Google is something I use a lot and try to put few codes together from examples, just a way I learn then reading books without hands-on trials.